# What is the equation of the learning rate decay in the Adam optimiser?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent, learning-rate, adam

Adam is known as an algorithm that has an adaptive learning rate for each parameter. I believe this is due to the division by the term $$v_t = \beta_2 \cdot v_{t-1} + (1-\beta_2) \cdot g_t^2 $$ Hence, each weight will get updated differently based on the accumulated squared gradients in their respective dimensions, even though $\alpha$ might be constant. [There are other StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517431/should-we-do-learning-rate-decay-for-adam-optimizer#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20absolutely.,learning%20rate%20decay%20using%20TensorFlow.) that have said that Adam has a built-in learning rate decay. In the original paper also, the [authors of adam paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980) says that the learning rate at time step $t$ decays based on the equation $$\alpha_t = \alpha \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-\beta_2^t}}{{1-\beta_1^t}}$$

Is the second equation the learning rate decay that has been built into the Adam algorithm?